# String occurance of characters for e.g. "aaaabbccccaadd" the answer to be "a4b2c4a2d2"

Tags: java, string

This question got asked by Monjim interview, I am able to do with brute force with time complexity of o(n2).

Solution is -

```
private static String wordCount(String word){
    String result = "";
    int k = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < word.length() ; i++){
        char temp = word.charAt(i);
        result += temp;
        int count = 0;
        while(k < word.length() && word.charAt(k) == temp){
            k++;
            count++;
            temp = word.charAt(i);
        }
        i=k;
        result += count;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Can anyone help me out with lesser time complexity.....

Comment: are you sure that is `O(n²)` and not `O(n)`? The outer loop is being *skipped* as often as the inner loop is being executed

Comment: but it has an error: infinite loop (for example with word `"abc"`) - *maybe* because `k` is **not** being set to `i` (or incremented) before starting the inner loop (that loop can actually be changed to use `i` directly no need for `k`)

Comment: actually  just change `i=k;`  to `i = k - 1; ` ( ì` will be incremented on next iteration) and it should work fine (and `O(n)`)

Comment: This is already O(n), it just has a small bug.

Comment: @MadhukarH If any helped you solve the issue, please consider accepting one of the posted answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With "aaaabbccccaadd" and the answer is "a4b2c4a2d2", I assume this is counting the consecutive words occurrance right? if so then you just need one loop O(n).

```
private static String wordCount(String word){
    if (word.isEmpty()) return "";
    
    String result = "";
    int k = 0;
    char currentChar = word.charAt(0);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < word.length() ; i++){
        if (currentChar != word.charAt(i)) {
            result += currentChar;
            result += String.valueOf(k);
            currentChar = word.charAt(i);
            k = 1;
        } else {
            k++;
        }
    }
    result += currentChar;
    result += String.valueOf(k);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is still O(n^2). Copying strings is O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple, imperative way to do it.

Initialize some fields

```
String s = "aaaabbccccaadd";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
char currentChar = s.charAt(0);
int count = 1;
```

- iterate over the string, counting until the character changes
- then append the character and the count to the StringBuilder. Then reset the `count` to `1` and assign `thisChar` to `currentChar`
- once the loop is done.
- append the last character and its count.

```
for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++) {
    char thisChar = s.charAt(i);
    if (currentChar == thisChar) {
        count++;
    } else {
        sb.append(currentChar).append(count);
        count = 1;
        currentChar = thisChar;
    }
}
sb.append(currentChar).append(count);
System.out.println(sb);
```

prints

```
a4b2c4a2d2
```

And here is a solution using regular expressions.

- `(.)` capture a single character
- `(\\1)*` followed by zero or more of the same character (uses a backreference).
- then append `group(1)`, the single character followed by the length of the entire `group(0)`.

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(.)(\\1)*").matcher(s);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while(matcher.find()) {
    sb.append(matcher.group(1)).append(matcher.group(0).length());
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

prints

```
a4b2c4a2d2
```

Comment: regular expression solution is awesome, thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the iterations, at least, by simply checking for a character change.
In your code, you are spawning a new loop, starting at *k*.

Here is an example.

```java
char[] chars = "aaaabbccccaadd".toCharArray();
char c;
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
s.append(c = chars[0]);
int b = 1;
for (int i = 1, n = chars.length; i < n; i++) {
    if (chars[i] == c) b++;
    else {
        if (b != 1) s.append(b);
        b = 1;
        s.append(c = chars[i]);
    }
}
s.append(b);
```

Your code will execute the same example string, "aaaabbccccaadd" in *19* iterations.
Whereas, this will execute it in *13*.

I have a few recommendations for your code.

Utilize variable declaration chains, and append *k* as a *for-loop* variable.
And, define a *length* variable to prevent the loop from calling *word.length* on every iteration.

```java
for(int i = 0, k = 0, n = word.length() ; i < n ; i++)
```

Also, declare *temp* outside of the *for-loop*, and place *count* as an additional variable.

```java
char temp;
for(int i = 0, k = 0, n = word.length(), count ; i < n ; i++)
```

Here is the re-factor.

```java
String result = "";
char temp;
for(int i = 0, k = 0, n = word.length(), count ; i < n ; i++){
    temp = word.charAt(i);
    result += temp;
    count = 0;
    while(k < n && word.charAt(k) == temp){
        k++;
        count++;
        temp = word.charAt(i);
    }
    i=k;
    result += count;
}

return result;
```